# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-onesignal:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: javascript, react-native, onesignal

After Installing one signal it throws below error in terminal

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-onesignal:compileDebugAidl'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-onesignal:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:12.+.
  >    Versions that do not match:
  >
  > - 17.0.0
  > - 16.0.0
  > - 15.0.1
  > - 15.0.0
  >     Required by:
  >      project :react-native-onesignal > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.2

NPM version
5.6.0

NODE version
9.8.0

Here is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.1.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-af-video-player": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.6",
    "react-native-searchbar": "^1.16.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.11.2"
}
```

1 Install one signal as per documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Like the message of the error, you should update the version. The support version does not match at this time.

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads : 16.0.0'
```

Comment: Try with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads : 18.3.0' but same error